# Não consigo conectar o banco de dados Mysql NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, node.js

Deveria mostrar os dadosda tabela na tela, mas não retorna nada. Onde estou errando?

```
module.exports = function(app){

app.get('/noticias', function(req, res){

   var mysql = require('mysql');

   var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host : 'localhost',
      user : 'root',
      password : '1234',
      database : 'portal_noticias'
   });

   connection.query('select * from noticias', function(error, result){
        res.send(result);
   });
   //res.render("noticias/noticias");
 });
};
```

Comment: Você está recebendo algum erro? Detalhe mais a sua pergunta seguindo o [guia de como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Você não está verificando os possíveis erros em momento algum. Sugiro as mudanças a seguir, assim os erros ocasionados serão mostrados e será mais fácil encontrar o problema:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const listar = async () => {
  const conexao = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '1234',
    database : 'portal_noticias'
  });

  const query = promisify(conexao.query);

  return query('select * from noticias');
};

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get('/noticias', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      res.send(await listar());
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
      res.status(500).send(e.message);
    }
  });
};
```